# How can I convert this date in PHP to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

Tags: php, date, format

This is the format I have:

```
Sunday, March 29 4:30 PM
```

This is the format I want:

```
2015-05-29 16:30:00
```

I tried:

```
Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateTime));
```

But it does not work. Any help?

Comment: Do you simply want to change the format, or actually change the date from March 29th to May 29th as well?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

(Just use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php))

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D, M d h:i A", "Sunday, March 29 4:30 PM");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

output:

```
2015-03-29 16:30:00
```